# Using a Custom Title Bar in an Electron JS App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I just started using the [`electron-react-boilerplate`](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) and currently trying to use a custom title bar by using the [`electron-titlebar`](https://github.com/Cristian006/electron-titlebar) package which was installed using `npm install --save eletron-titlebar`.

Based on my very weak understanding of the electron boilerplate and electron in general, I tried what the `electron-titlebar` docs suggested and introduced the `<TitleBar>` component on the same level as the `children` element of the `Root` component, resulting in the code below.

**Problem:** However whenever the `<TitleBar>` component is there, we get a blank screen. Removing the component give us back our original DOM elements, but obviously, no title bar since we just removed it.

An error is also shown in the JS console

> react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

What is the correct way to use `electron-titlebar` with the `electron-react-boilerplate` setup?

**/app/containers/App.js**

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import TitleBar from 'electron-titlebar';

type Props = {
  children: React.Node
};

export default class App extends React.Component<Props> {
  props: Props;

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <TitleBar
          title="Electron"
        />
        {children}
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just starting messing around with Electron myself and ran into this error. I was able to solve it by changing my import to require:

```
const TitleBar = require('frameless-titlebar');
```